# Copying files from USB drive fails - I/O error or Invalid Argument

Tags: file-copy

I'm trying to copy files from an USB stick to another drive. At least the file names appear to be corrupt, `ls` shows them as:

```
'ZHECMIv'$'\027''.PDF'
'ZHEKMI>2.P─F'
 ZHENIL~1.PDF
'эeloѤyfɯrɥvdr.2uOroä䁲igez_o_聴eŢe'$'\340\240\256''Ű聤f'
'ၙa⁯n­P⁩ѥòѳen-ၐoint-M䁯rѴ&`df'
```

Copying fails with errors like these:

```
cp: error reading '/media/pg/VERBATIM/2012/03/MVANES~0.PDF': Input/output error
cp: cannot create regular file '/media/pg/Elements SE/verba/2012/03/ERANmS~3.P'$'\004''B': Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat '/media/pg/VERBATIM/2014/09/f5'$'\004''7'$'\004''0'$'\004''.': No such file or directory
```

On the chance that only the filenames are corrupt, I tried this:

```
pg@TREX:~$ cp /media/pg/VERBATIM/2012/02/'YQ83A1'$'\177''0.╨DF' ./1.pdf
cp: error reading '/media/pg/VERBATIM/2012/02/YQ83A1'$'\177''0.╨DF': Input/output error
```

`fsck.vfat -n` shows:

```
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  65:01/00
  Not automatically fixing this.
FATs differ but appear to be intact.
  Using first FAT.
Cluster 113918 out of range (67222785 > 1968189). Setting to EOF.
Cluster 113928 out of range (2211211 > 1968189). Setting to EOF.
Cluster 113929 out of range (67222860 > 1968189). Setting to EOF.
Cluster 113937 out of range (2211092 > 1968189). Setting to EOF.
...
Cluster 657871 out of range (1). Setting to EOF. (Several)
...
Cluster 1940714 out of range (1342259Internal error: next_cluster on bad cluster
52 > 1968189). Setting to EOF. (once)
```

`fdisk -l` output:

```
pg@TREX:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sde
Disk /dev/sde: 30.05 GiB, 32262586368 bytes, 63012864 sectors
Disk model: STORE N GO      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sde1          32 63012863 63012832  30G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Are these files lost for good, or is there a tool I can try to recover them with?

- Debian Bullseye fully up to date
- `$LANG` is set to en_US.UTF.8
- USB stick 32GB, VFAT
- Data added to drive with Win10 Pro

Comment: Filenames are corrupted or you just don't get support for the matching codepage ?

Comment: `ddrescue` could be your best bet.

Comment: Not a codepage issue. Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov, ddrescue just now running.

Comment: Make sure it's **not** overheating. Heat may as well kill the remaining cells.

Comment: Thx again @ArtemS.Tashkinov. It's a mini-USB drive, so can't do much abt that. So far doesn't feel hot, ddrescue shows 8.1% rescued, only 5 more hours to go. Good thing I don't need this system just now :D

Comment: If you have a small fan it would be great if you directed its flow towards the device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cp: error reading <filename>: Input/output error` indicates there is corruption in locations other than filenames too.

The `fdisk` output is normal for a GPT-partitioned external disk. The size does not match the 32 GB you said, but 1.82 TiB is consistent with the disk model `Elements SE 25FD` reported by `fdisk`: are you really targeting the correct disk with your `fdisk` command?

Based on the `cp` commands output, it looks like you listed the `fdisk` output of the disk you are recovering files **to**, rather than the USB stick you are recovering them **from**.

I would suggest using `ddrescue` to image the failing USB stick and working on the copy, and/or using [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to try and recover the files since it is designed for rescuing files from failing flash-type media.

Comment: Oopsie. Yes, I mixed the drives with `fdisk` and `fsck.vfat`. The problematic one is /dev/sde. Question edited. Thanks for the suggestion, `ddrescue` and PhotoRec are till now unknown to me, trying that path now.

Comment: The files are all PDFs, sheet music collected over years. PhotoRec can't open any of the ones I tested. Looks like the whole thing is borked, probably killed by heat as ArtemiS suggested. I anyway got the image created, and at least some of the files are still readable, so solution accepted. Thanks a bunch again.